# Jabref custom export to html not working

Tags: html, linux, export, bibtex

I am trying to export my entries from a jabref database to an html file.  I went to 'manage custom exports' and added the directory where the main layout file and the begin and end files are located.  The layout files look like this:

newHtmlBib.begin.layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JabRef References output</title>
<style type="text/css">
body { font-size: 100%; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

newHtmlBib.layout:

```
<p>\begin{author}<b>\format[AuthorLastFirst,AuthorAbbreviator,AuthorAndsReplacer,HTMLChars]{\author}\end{author}</b>&nbsp;\begin{year}<b>\year</b>\end{year}.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\begin{title}\format[HTMLChars]{\title}\end{title}.\begin{editor}
In \format[AuthorLastFirst,AuthorAbbreviator,AuthorAndsReplacer,HTMLChars]{\editor} <i>(ed.)</i>\end{editor}\begin{chapter}
\format[HTMLChars]{\chapter}\end{chapter}\begin{journal}
<em>\format[HTMLChars]{\journal}, </em>\end{journal}
\begin{booktitle}<i>\format[HTMLChars]{\booktitle}</i>\end{booktitle}
\begin{school}<em>\format[HTMLChars]{\school}, </em>\end{school}\begin{institution}<em>\format[HTMLChars]{\institution}, </em>\end{institution}\begin{publisher}<em>\format[HTMLChars]{\publisher}, </em>\end{publisher}\begin{volume}<i>, \volume</i>\end{volume}\begin{pages}, \format[FormatPagesForHTML]{\pages}\end{pages}
</p>
```

newHtmlBib.end.layout:

```
</body>
</html>
```

However, after exporting my entries, this is what I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>JabRef references</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
body { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
dt { margin-top: 1em; font-weight: bold; }
@media print {
dt { page-break-after: avoid; }
dd { page-break-before: avoid; }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<dl>
<dt>inproceedings <a name="Barzdicnvs2008">(Barzdicnvs2008)</a></dt>
<dd>B&#257;rzdi&#326;&#353;, G., Gr&#363;z&#299;tis, N., Ne&#353;pore, G., Saul&#299;te, B., Auzicdna, I. and Lev&#257;ne-Petrova, K.</dd>
<dd><i>Multidimensional Ontologies: Integration of Frame Semantics and Ontological Semantics</i></dd>
<dd>Proceedings of the XIII Euralex International Congress</dd>
<dd><b>2008</b>, pp. 277-283</dd>

<dt>incollection <a name="Carbonell1982">(Carbonell1982)</a></dt>
<dd>Carbonell, J. G.</dd>
<dd><i>Metaphor: An inescapable phenomenon</i></dd>
<dd>Lehnert, W. G. &amp; Ringle, M. H. <i>(ed.)</i></dd>
<dd>Strategies for Natural Language Processing</dd>
<dd>Erlbaum, <b>1982</b>, pp. 415-434</dd>

<dt>inproceedings <a name="Carbonell1980">(Carbonell1980)</a></dt>
<dd>Carbonell, J. G.</dd>
<dd><i>Metaphor-- a key to extensible semantic analysis</i></dd>
<dd>ACL Proceedings, 18th Annual Meeting</dd>
<dd><b>1980</b>, pp. 17-21</dd>

<dt>unpublished <a name="Tewari2003">(Tewari2003)</a></dt>
<dd>Tewari, A.</dd>
<dd><i>Detecting metaphors involving motion verbs in online business news sources</i>  </dd>
<dd><b>2003</b></dd>

</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems to me like some default export filter is overriding my custom filter.  What I was hoping to get was an html document that has the entries shown like this:

```
<a name="Carbonell1980">(Carbonell1980)</a>
<dd>Carbonell, J. G.</dd>
<dd><i>Metaphor-- a key to extensible semantic analysis</i></dd>
<dd>ACL Proceedings, 18th Annual Meeting</dd>
<dd><b>1980</b>, pp. 17-21</dd>

<a name="Tewari2003">(Tewari2003)</a>
<dd>Tewari, A.</dd>
<dd><i>Detecting metaphors involving motion verbs in online business news sources</i></dd>
<dd><b>2003</b></dd>
```

Any ideas as to what is happening when I export?

I am pretty new to both Linux and Jabref, so perhaps (hopefully) it is something fairly easy...

Thanks!!